# Are nested tabs acceptable on mobile?

Tags: mobile, navigation, information-architecture, tabs

There's an app in which the users can see all the services scheduled for they which has the following architecture.

- My services

  - Day of the week

    - Appointment
- Messages
- My profile

Right now, the app is designed with two nested tab bars to navigate through sections and (when you're in "My services") through days. But that just feel weird.

[image]

Also I know that it's not desirable to have various actions triggered by the same gesture (in this case the swipe), but I can find out another way to arrange the information.

FTR. In tests, users have been struggling with this, since they expect the normal through-tabs navigation and it usually just goes through days of the week.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to Material design [Tabs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage) and [Navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns). According to it **Tabs should not be nested**.

My suggestion is that you consider a different type of Navigation for your second tab level.

[image]

---

[image]

> **Don't.**
>
> Tabs should not be nested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "My Services" use "Appointments". Users will expect some sort of day-oriented interface.

So the navigation would be:

- Appointments
- Messages
- Profile (Why "My"? Who else's profile would it be? By the same
  reasoning everything should have "My" in front of it.)

Then you could have days as a stacked list (Date, description) and tapping on a day expands to show details (or if there are only a few details just show them in the list).